# Is there any reason for using Linear Queues vs Circular Queues?

Tags: data-structures, queue

It seems to be from everything I read that Circular Queues are far better than Linear Queues in many ways.
[Why implement Queues vs Circular Queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755139/why-implement-queues-as-circular-array)

So is there any reason to ever use Linear Queues?

Comment: If you want a unlimited/dynamic number of slots it doe's not matter.